# ORA-0092 invalid datatype - cannot find error

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, create-table

Tried to check each data type and fix the error. Tried to also create a table without a primary key, but I still get the same error.

```
create table Training_MarieS
 (request_id numeric (20) not null, 
  parameter_name varchar2(128 BYTE) not null,
  parameter_value varchar2(128 BYTE) not null,
  service_symbol varchar2(128 BYTE) not null,
  service_type  varchar2(20),
  parameter_description text,
  date_time timestamp not null, 
  CONSTRAINT request_id PRIMARY KEY (request_id)
);
```

Comment: I guess that you're talking about Oracle DB, right?
There are no numeric data type, please review:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm

Comment: `numeric` is deprecated, use `number` instead. `text` is not valid, use `varchar`, `clob`, or `lob` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to create a table using MySQL datatypes in Oracle. As you've seen, this won't work.

- Oracle's equivalent of `numeric` is `number`
- Oracle's equivalent of `text` is `clob`

```sql
create table Training_MarieS
 (request_id NUMBER (20) not null, -- Here!
  parameter_name varchar2(128 BYTE) not null,
  parameter_value varchar2(128 BYTE) not null,
  service_symbol varchar2(128 BYTE) not null,
  service_type  varchar2(20),
  parameter_description CLOB, -- And here!
  date_time timestamp not null, 
  CONSTRAINT request_id PRIMARY KEY (request_id)
);
```